# Javascript - Count all combinations of consecutive words in a submit

Tags: javascript

I am trying to count all combinations of matching strings in a textarea submit.

Eg:

USA Canada UK Australia Japan India

USA Canada India UK Australia China Brazil France

Brazil France Australia China

Expected results

2 consecutive words string match :

```
UK Australia = 2
USA Canada = 2
Brazil France = 2
Australia China = 2
```

1 consecutive words string match :

```
Canada UK = 1
Australia Japan = 1
Japan India = 1
India UK = 1
Australia China = 1
China Brazil = 1
France Australia = 1
```

I'm a beginner and just thinking about it gives me a headache.

Thank you for your time and it would be great if someone can help to write this function or point me to use any existing package, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: `write this function` Have you made any attempt to write any code yourself yet?

Comment: Match what exactly?

Comment: Can you clarify the logic of your matching? You have two-word matches like `Brazil France` and one-word matches `Australia China`.  Why is one a 1 word match and the other a 2 word match.

Comment: I guess you start looking for two word pairs, so "USA Canada", then "Canada UK", then "UK Australia" and so on. You might then do three word: "USA Canada UK" etc, then four word "USA Canada UK Australia", etc. Of course you want to skip a match if you've already found it.

Comment: Sorry guys, I've made some errors on my initial post that I've fixed, You are so fast lol. I just want to tell the user how many time each combination of words he has in his submitted text (2 consecutive words, 3 consecutive words,,,,).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```js
var string = ['USA Canada UK Australia Japan India', 'USA Canada India UK Australia China Brazil France', 'Brazil France Australia China']
string = string.join(' ')
var words = string.split(' ')

var wordGroups = {}
for( let i=1; i< words.length; i++ ){
  let key = words[ i-1 ]+ '_' + words[ i ]
  if( !wordGroups[ key ]) {
    wordGroups[ key ] = 0
  }
  wordGroups[ key ] = wordGroups[ key ] + 1
}

Object.keys( wordGroups ).forEach( key =>{
  let word = key.replace('_', ' ');
  console.log( word , ': ', wordGroups[ key ])
})
```

Comment: Thank you Gans. Your answer is the closest to what I intend to do expect that the user submits a textarea so it's not a string but an array and that's where it's difficult for me.

Comment: so the input is like this ---- var string = ['USA Canada UK Australia Japan India',
'USA Canada India UK Australia China Brazil France',
'Brazil France Australia China']
right?

Comment: Right, it's an array

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way....

```
const arrayOfWords = "USA Canada UK Australia Japan India USA Canada India UK Australia China Brazil France Brazil France Australia China".split(" ");
const arrayOfPairs=[];

for(let i = 0;i<arrayOfWords.length-1;i++){
    arrayOfPairs.push(arrayOfWords.slice(i,i+2).join(" "));
}

/* console.log(arrayOfPairs); */

const obj = arrayOfPairs.reduce((arr,ele,index)=>{
  if(arr[ele]){
      arr[ele] += 1;
      return arr;
  }
  arr[ele]=1;
  return arr;
},{})

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thank you for help, but the input is more of an array than a string. Your help is much appreciated.